# Best Approach to list news items with paging in MVC2 .net

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

What would be the best approach to list news items with paging from MVC2 .net?

Comment: How that "news" item is structured and how do you want to represent it (plain grid, Google News-like article list, ...)?

Comment: Similar to google news if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at [MVContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid).